# Unable to format the query properly in `db.Exec`, and throws an error

Tags: sql, mysql, go

I am using the database/mysql and mysql driver package to execute a command
`GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'test1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'passoword`

The following code throws an error

Error 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?@? IDENTIFIED BY ?' at line 1

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

var db *sql.DB

func main() {
    // Capture connection properties.
    cfg := mysql.Config{
        User:   "root",
        Passwd: "example",
        Net:    "tcp",
        Addr:   "127.0.0.1:3306",
        DBName: "test",
    AllowNativePasswords: true,
    }
    // Get a database handle.
    var err error
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", cfg.FormatDSN())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    pingErr := db.Ping()
    if pingErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(pingErr)
    }
    fmt.Println("Connected!")


    _, err = db.Exec("GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ?@? IDENTIFIED BY ?","test1", "%", "test1")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        }

    
}
```

I have tried

`db.Exec("GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO '?'@'?' IDENTIFIED BY '?'","test1", "%", "test1")`

result
`sql: expected 0 arguments, got 3`

Comment: The error is pretty clear. What part do you need help with?

Comment: my understanding is that the replacement of ? is not happening so the error.`check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?@? IDENTIFIED BY ?' at line 1`

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/prepare-statement/ says: *"Parameter markers can be used only where expressions should appear, __not for SQL keywords, identifiers, and so forth__."*... I don't know about the `host_name` but the `user_name` part of [Account Names](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-user/#account-names) seems to be considered an __identifer__, which, if that's the case, means that you can't use `?` for providing the `user_name` value to the query, instead you have to use plain string concatenation or interpolation.

Comment: Try `db.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO %s IDENTIFIED BY ?", "test1@'%'"), "test1"`).

Comment: yes, the above works replacing all ?. is this the only way? I want to avoid using `fmt.Sprintf` for sql injection danger.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in mysql https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28406 which prevents using variables in the GRANT password.

only replacing the varibales using fmt.Sprintf() seems to work.